# How to build effective K-means algoritham?

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I have written a simple K-mean algorithm, But I am finding difficulty to explore it cluster by cluster.

Github Link: https://github.com/AkshayBayas/Machine-learning-/blob/master/K-Means%20algorithm.ipynb

Code:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import seaborn as sns    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

%matplotlib inline    
%pylab    

Df = pd.read_csv('Kdata.csv') 
   
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
KModule = KMeans()    
K_model = KModule.fit(Df)    
K_result = K_model.predict(Df)    
centers = K_model.cluster_centers_    
K_model.labels_    
plt.scatter (x1,x2, c = K_model.labels_, cmap = 'rainbow' )
```

[image: K-mean figure]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you mean by "explore cluster by cluster".

If you don't specify the number of clusters, by default it is 8, so if you start with 3 like the code below, you can separate them. Also you need to set it as categoric, the cluster, so it will not be colored on a continuous scale:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import seaborn as sns    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Df = pd.read_csv('Kdata.csv') 

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
KModule = KMeans(n_clusters=3)    
K_model = KModule.fit(Df)    
K_result = K_model.predict(Df)

Df['cluster'] = pd.Categorical(K_model.labels_)
       
sns.scatterplot("V1","V2",data=Df,hue='cluster',cmap = 'rainbow' )
```

[image]

`Df.plot.scatter("V1","V2",c='cluster',cmap = 'rainbow')`

[image]